# Android button position in table row

Tags: android, button, layout

I have a table layout with a button in its lowest row:

```
<TableRow>

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/name" >
    </TextView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left" >
    </EditText>
</TableRow>

<TableRow>

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/frist_name" >
    </TextView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/firstName"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left" >
    </EditText>
</TableRow>

<TableRow>

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/telephone" >
    </TextView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/telephone"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left" >
    </EditText>
</TableRow>
<TableRow>

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/userName" >
    </TextView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userName"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left" >
    </EditText>
</TableRow>
<TableRow>

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/password" >
    </TextView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left" >
    </EditText>
</TableRow>
<TableRow>


    <Button

        android:id="@+id/saveMasterDataButton"
        android:text="@string/save"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|fill_horizontal"


        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

</TableRow>
```

My Problem ist that the button is always by default out of alignment with the text content in the same column above it by 1 or 2 mm to the right. I fiddled around with various tricks, removing the shade, but the results where never satisfactory.

Here is how this button looks like:[Save button out of alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fatli.jpg)

Thanks

Matthias

Comment: Would you like the texts to be aligned or the text and the button edge? Consider adding a screenshot to clarify.

Comment: @Matthias Can you explain in detail that what you exactly want??

Comment: Hello 0X0nosugar, I have attached an image of the button in my post. Can you make something out now?